# "Next tag badge" panel score and answers counter discrepancy

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

On the "Next tag badge" panel of [my Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) for C# tag, I see:

> 92/100 score
>   88/20 answers

[image: Next tag badge]

But, when I open the "Select your next badge" panel, there's:

> 97/100 score
>   90/20 answers

[image: Select your next badge]

---

I'm not sure which one is correct. But I believe that both displays should show the same counts.

The discrepancy is not due to a caching, I've noticed it the first time many weeks ago.

For these particular current counts: I have a single C# answer with 3 votes only in the last 5 days, last upvoted 13 hours ago (2015-10-12 19:30:05Z). So it should not cause the 5 votes and 2 answers difference.

I believe that the counters on the "Select your next badge" are correct and the counters on the "Next tag badge" are wrong, as I have:

> Asked 1 non-wiki question with a total score of 6. **Gave 90 non-wiki answers with a total score of 97.**

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a850848%20[c%23]%20is%3aanswer

---

Today (2015-10-16), the "Next tag badge" got bumped to 97/100. But "Select your next badge" shows 98/100 already.

Comment: I am having this issue on CodeReview right now as well.  any updates?

Comment: Same here, on CodeReview as well, tracking a bronze badge worked OK, but as soon as I reached it, the silver badge was displayed as tracked but the counters were frozen. Selecting the silver badge again as suggested by @VictorStafusa seems to fix it.

Comment: Same issue everywhere. I was just considering to report it, but looks like I am not the only one. Any resolution? What would the progress bar be for if you had to click it to get it updated?

Comment: Same issue for me too on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

A workaround for this bug is to choose a different tag badge to track in the "Select your next badge panel" and then open the panel again to select back the tag badge that you really want to track. This should make the tag badge tracking get properly sync'ed.

Comment: this seems like a workaround and not a solution/bug fix.

Comment: @Malachi Do you know a solution/fix for this? If yes, please, post it as an answer.

Comment: no I don't, and that is why I posted a comment on the question and upvoted.  this is more of a bug report than a "who has an answer" type of thing

Comment: @Malachi And as a bug report, providing information about how to workaround it is important for our fellow users who are looking for some information about it.

Comment: @Malachi No! The question proposes a problem (in this case, a bug report) and answers proposes solutions (in my case a workaround for the bug). And yes, a workaround IS a possible solution afterall. In this specific case, by performing the workaround that I described, the user wil be able to see his/her correct badge tracking data. If I modified the question OTOH, then I would be changing the author intention, which is not the way to go because as a general rule, edits should preserve the original author intentions in order to not face the risk of being reverted.

Comment: this is a coding issue, and should be handled by StackExchange staff.

Comment: @Malachi is correct, and it can take long weeks, months, and even years for non-critical bugs like this to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be fixed. I can't reproduce it anymore.