# How to achieve a gold tag badge

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges, tag-score

I am currently following a gold tag badge for javascript, it's description says *earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non community wiki answers in the tag*, what I understand from this is I need to earn 1000 reputation by answering atleast 200 questions which are tagged as JavaScript and which are non community wiki.

I am like really earning a lot of reputation daily but my tag score is constant to 581/1000 from past week, but my reputation gain is more then 1000 in the past week (mostly by answering Javascript based questions only).

I think SO Community should bring more clarity on how to earn this bade exactly.

I have a few doubts though:

1. Non community wiki posts are those which are asked by a normal user and are not marked as community wiki. I think i need to answer these questions and if i will get upvotes my score for gold badge will increase (Which is not increasing at all).
2. Should javascript be one of the tag on that question or it should be the only badge on that question?

Comment: This is actually a known, long time bug. The way to "fix" it is described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269825/152859). You can see your actual tag scores [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1496715/void?tab=tags), and you have score of 653 and not 581.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 653 is the number of answer i have posted, and 581 is my score. Correct me if i am wrong here.

Comment: Wrong indeed, When in doubt, hover: http://i.stack.imgur.com/W38TT.png

Comment: And @ShadowWizard please comment on this `Non community wiki posts are those which are asked by a normal user and are not marked as community wiki. I think i need to answer these questions and if i will get upvotes my score for gold badge will increase`?

Comment: My pleasure, and hope that irritating bug of frozen score will be fixed. :)

Comment: Regarding the "Non community wiki posts" yes you are correct. These days new questions marked as CW are very rare, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah thanks, last thing, In how much time the actual tag badge score refreshes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/961/discussion-between-shadow-wizard-and-void).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Score is net upvotes, not reputation.

Lots of things in your profile are cached. You will see a delay between events occurring, and some of them being reflected in your profile.

And badge-awarding happens periodically: not as soon as the goal is reached, but some hours afterwards, the next time the badge process runs.

Comment: But I am getting lots of upvotes but no increase in my score?

Comment: In how much time the score updates? Like does it take more then a week or it reflects instantly?