# Do the tag scores now update more often?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-badges, tag-score

I've posted an answer on Meta Stack Overflow four hours ago. Appears it was my twentieth answer with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, so I got the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag badge. I was surprised because the tag badges are usually awarded around UTC 3:00 AM. Well I thought, maybe the script was too late.

Then it got downvoted, and to my greater surprise, my tag scores soon went down too. Again, I'd expect it to happen at UTC 3:00 AM.

Has something changed recently?

---

The tag scores have already updated **twice** since ([current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBtPC.png)), which seems to be inline with the downvotes I was getting. Now I've removed the answer, let's see if I get the badge revoked and the scores updated again.

---

The score of the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag [has been just updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a84Xv.png). Strangely enough, [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) isn't updating inline with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and the tag badge is still here.

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), after a delay, [has its score updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqZTS.png) (the badge is still here...).

So yes, the score *definitely* updates now more often.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they do not update any more frequently, at least not globally.

What does happen is the *badge progress tracker* keeps track of one tag badge in real time, and will update your tag score more frequently and award you the tag badge much sooner than waiting for the script if you qualify. But this *only* happens for the tag badge currently being tracked. (There are *some* other precautions in there to prevent users from just flipping through tags in the tracker to update all of their tag scores manually.)

Comment: Ah, got it! Yep, I did switch the badges today, didn't think it's the reason to update. I've tracked [discussion] first, then switched to [feature-request]. Interesting.

Comment: You should answer [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267818/next-tag-badge-panel-score-and-answers-counter-discrepancy) too.

Comment: @nicael I don't have an answer for that one. The tracker does sometimes break and stops updating the scores until it gets reset. That needs to be fixed.

Comment: Ok then, that's a pity.

Comment: 6-8  pities, @nicael. ;)