# Incorrect Tag Scores in Profile Activity Summary

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-score

### Issue:

My [profile summary on SO Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7690806/ragefoxx?tab=topactivity) shows that I have one answer and all of that answer's current tags show in the Tag section, however the points of the answer do not align with the points of (all) the tags.

An image just in case it does resolve itself over time to show what I am referring to specifically:

[image: An image just in case it does resolve itself over time to show what I am referring to specifically]

### What I have looked at:

First I thought perhaps my answer was answered before the tags were added and thus incorrectly tallied, explaining that one of the tags shows the correct value but the other tags don't.  It does appear that all of the tags that were added after are incorrectly tallied, but they were *all* added *before* my answer.

- `discussion` Tag (Question Asked): `2020-02-04 00:43:22Z`
- `stack-exchange` and `community` Tags: `2020-02-04 00:53:34Z`
- `featured` Tag: `2020-02-04 00:54:08Z`
- `welcoming` Tag: `2020-02-04 17:06:42Z`
- My Answer: `2020-02-05 00:34:49Z`

I've cleared caches, checked with multiple browsers (Firefox and Chrome), and the results show the same metric.  I thought perhaps caching on SO server side, but that would be odd because the tags were all added same day and all nearly a day before my answer besides one (and the numbers don't show that one differently than the other added tags).

As for the reason I am posting this here as opposed to there:  I have only noticed this issue on SO Meta specifically, however I do not have very many data points to say that this could not be an issue elsewhere.

A similar question was asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run) *(I like that the similar questions was able to pick that out)*, but the status has been marked completed. It also appears to be an ongoing issue that keeps surfacing without any additional word.  I don't think it is the same because one of the five tags in question is actually the correct value.

**Is this something that will resolve itself given time, or is this a bug that needs to be revisited?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *tracking* the `discussion` badge:

> [image]

Tracking a badge [causes it to be updated *much more frequently throughout the day*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272883/do-the-tag-scores-now-update-more-often). As people upvote your one post you’ll see the tag score follow suit.

However, every other tag follows the normal once-every-24-hours update schedule.