# Illuminator Badge Requirements

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

Yesterday I answered [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44489/cis-trans-interconversion-of-crotyl-boron-compounds) on Chemistry SE.  Immediately after submitting the answer, and before any upvotes were received, I edited the question.  Later, I received some upvotes on my answer but noticed that my Illuminator badge score did not increase.  Why didn't it tick up by one, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might just be caching. Your answer certainly meets all the requirements. The question and the answer are barely a day old. I would wait for 12 more hours before wondering this.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. This has happened to me too many times to be a caching problem.

Comment: Also, the progress counters often "freeze", it's a [known bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267818/next-tag-badge-panel-score-and-answers-counter-discrepancy). Try tracking a different badge, then back to Illuminator and see if it helps.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but it didn't change the Illuminator badge count.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: Well, it's currently on 134. If within 24 hours it will still not become 135 then there might be a bug here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That bug only happens with the tag badges. At least, I've never seen a report for the main badges freezing. But I also don't know exactly how this particular badge gets tracked, or when the counter increments. Some of the trackers are a lot less "real-time" than others.

Comment: @animuson agreed. Perhaps only a daily job, hence my previous comment asking to wait 24 hours just to be sure.