# Does the Help Center wording for Illuminator badge need adjusting?

Tags: support, badges, help-center, wording, edit-and-answer-badges

From the [FAQ here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/392799):

> Illuminator
>
> - gold; awarded once
> - Edit 500 questions each within 12 hours of answering it (score>0).

But from the **go-to** [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/96/illuminator):

> Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0).

The wording suggests that the order doesn't matter (I certainly thought so), but the order as it turns out, matters. Since it is the last badge I'm yet to earn on Aviation, I've noticed the counter does not always count when an edit + answer are within 12 hours.

After [checking SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/1425251/illuminator-badge-progress-test-for-showing-the-question-link-where-earned-credi) against my answers where I edited the question, the total sum on SEDE matches the counter (so the query is correct), but those where I edited first are not counted and do not show on SEDE.

This causes confusion, e.g. [Illuminator Badge Requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273925/392799)

So, my suggested wording:

> Answer *then* edit 500 questions (editing within 12 hours *after* answering; answer score > 0).

**Or,** if this behavior was not intended (i.e. either action can come first, i.e. [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)), then the counter needs fixing please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The wording suggests that the order doesn't matter (I certainly thought so), but the order as it turns out, matters.

The order *does not* matter, not for the badge counter and not for the SEDE query (it has an `abs` on the last line). Of course, if your edit is more than twelve hours before the answer, then it does not count. And tag-only edits to the question don't count either. Incidentally, the moment of the upvotes to your answer don't matter.

> but those where I edited first are not counted and do not show on SEDE.

I *am* curious for some examples of this. E.g. [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/89985/8282) you only edited the tags (and your answer is from Sunday evening, after the last SEDE refresh).

Comment: *tag-only edits to the question don't count* – maybe this is it? If yes, IMO it needs clarification.

Comment: @ymb1 it's in the FAQ "Only body and title edits on the question count, tag-only edits do not." and tag-only edits don't count as real edits in a couple of other places.

Comment: Oh! *Additional criteria.* I thought that was the next badge and didn't read after the two bullet points. My bad!

Comment: RE *I am curious for some examples* – I don't see that one on SEDE; I'm confused what's the issue with that one since it's tag-only edit?

Comment: I meant if you have any examples of edit-then-answer you think should count (but you don't see in the SEDE query).

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be slightly adjusted for clarity, but mainly because to me the wording 'both actions within 12 hours' implies that you need to edit/answer 500 questions **all within** 12 hours!

So if you somehow managed to answer/edit a whopping 499 questions but then didn't do the same for a 500th before the 12 hours is up, you would have to start all over again.

I know this may seem somewhat ridiculous but this was my initial thought (and ultimately what led me to find this question that you have asked)!

Comment: "Both" implies that we're talking about only two things, and from the context it's clear that those two things are editing and answering. Now, "*all* actions within 12 hours" would have the implication you say.

Comment: As there are only two things being talked about, surely 'both' and 'all' could be used interchangeably in this context? Or have I misunderstood what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, but "both" implies *exactly* two things. What I am saying is that "both actions within 12 hours" means that *two actions* must have occurred within 12 hours. The interpretation offered in this answer is that "both actions within 12 hours" means "all 500 pairs of actions within 12 hours", which makes less sense to me because "both" can't refer to 500 things.

Comment: Same here. I thought this is an impossible badge